# Pandas read_table() thousands=',' not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in some population data as an exercise to learn pandas:

```
>>> countries = pd.read_table('country_data.txt',
                             thousands=',',
                             header=None,
                             names=["Country Name", "Area (km^2)", "Areami2",
                                    "Population", "Densitykm2", "Densitymi2",
                                    "Date", "Source"],
                             usecols=["Country Name", "Area (km^2)", "Population"],
                             index_col="Country Name"
                             )
>>> countries.head()
```

gives

```
                Area (km^2) Population
Country Name        
Monaco             2     36,136
Singapore        716     5,399,200
Vatican City     0.44    800
Bahrain          757     1,234,571
Malta            315     416,055
```

where even though I specified thousands=',', it looks like the populations are being read as strings:

```
>>> countries.ix["Singapore"]["Population"]
'5,399,200'
```

I've tried moving the "thousands=','" bit around in the call to read_table, and also inspected the data to see if something was being screwed up, but there's only numeric values there, and I don't know where else to look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a bug in 0.12](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322), and has been fixed in (soon to be released) 0.13.

Until then, I suggest munging the columns manually:

```
In [11]: df['Population'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)  # or float
Out[11]: 
0      36136
1    5399200
2        800
3    1234571
4     416055
Name: Population, dtype: int64

In [12]: df['Population'] = df['Population'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```